# Create password protected Samba storage pool

Tags: python, api, libvirt

```
<pool type="netfs">
  <name>virtimages</name>
  <source>
    <host name="0.0.0.0"/>
    <dir path="/var/lib/virt/images"/>
    <format type='cifs'/>
  </source>
  <target>
    <path>/var/lib/virt/images</path>
  </target>
</pool>
```

The above libvirt XML configuration can be used to create a Samba storage pool but how do I create a password protected Samba storage pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an auth section inside your source, for example:

````
  <name>YourStorage</name>
  <source>
    <host name="storage.example.com" />
    <dir path="/backup" />
    <format type="cifs" />
    <auth type='chap' username='SomeSecretUsername'>
      <secret usage='SomeSecretPass'/>
    </auth>
  </source>
  <target>
    <path>/mnt/storage</path>
  </target>
</pool>```

See: https://libvirt.org/formatstorage.html#StoragePoolSource
````